# How do I return one of the conditions of a multi-condition if statement in an Excel macro?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I know that all cells in column A will contain one value from a set of values. Generally there is other text in the cell, which is why I can't just use the cell's value. In this case, it's cities, so for example: San Francisco, New York, and Seattle.

My goal is to make a multi-conditional macro which, once one of its conditions has been met, will put that exact condition in a particular cell. So in my example, one of the conditions would be that the cell contains Seattle. So if cell A3 contains "Seattle" then I want the macro to put "Seattle" into cell B3. Or, if cell A3 contains "New York" then I want it to put "New York" into cell B3. And so on. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't pretty, but you could use something like this in Cell B3:

```
=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("San Francisco",A3),0),"San Francisco",IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("New York",A3),0),"New York",IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("Seattle",A3),0),"Seattle","")))
```

To make it easier to see:

```
IF(
    IFERROR(SEARCH("San Francisco",A3),0)
    ,"San Francisco"
    ,IF(
        IFERROR(SEARCH("New York",A3),0)
        ,"New York"
        ,IF(
            IFERROR(SEARCH("Seattle",A3),0)
            ,"Seattle"
            ,""
        )
    )
)
```

To break it down, basically you use SEARCH to find if it contains a text string, and it returns 1 or #VALUE! I then use IFERROR to handle #VALUE! and instead change it to a 0.

The IF statements are nested:

```
IF (San Francisco)
[true]  "San Francisco"
[false] IF (New York)
        [true]  "New York"
        [false] IF (Seattle)
                [true]  "Seattle"
                [false] ""
```

Comment: Yup, that makes sense, SEARCH is useful for this. There's probably a similar way to do this with a macro, I'll figure it out later.

Comment: If you need to use it in a macro, you can use `InStr` in something like this: `If InStr(1, (Range("A3").Value), "San Fransisco") > 0 Then ...` and use the same logic as above